# -[AVPlayerViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, retain, avplayerviewcontroller, uibubbletableview

I am trying to add an `AVPlayerViewController` to a chat bubble so that any audio or video messages when received can be directly played in the chat bubble. My `UITableView` list contains many of these bubbles. But when I try to scroll the table view, the app gets crashed showing -`[AVPlayerViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance.`

Here below is my code for adding a `AVPlayerViewController` object to each chat bubble :-

```
_playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
_playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
_playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 5.0, 190.0 , 90.0);  //   self.view.bounds;
_playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

[_playerViewController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[_playerViewController .view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
[cell.contentview addsubview:_playerViewController.view];
```

the url contains the file path (audio/video), and I am trying to add the  `_playerViewController` object to `UITableView` cell's content view, but it throws the above error. Can anyone please tell me what I should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every cell should not contain `AVPlayerViewController`. It's horrible!

You should manage your stuff like every cell just display thumbnail of your video and you should manage array of urls of videos. now use common `AVPlayerViewController` to play any video. I mean when user tap cell or play button of cell then pass that url to player and play video!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you also tell me the logic for playing audio files please.

Comment: @Lion-should i use the same player too play the audio files?

Comment: you can create a action method that create and plays video (similar code as you have shown in question). then on button click or in `didselectrow` pass selected video url to these method and create AVPlayerViewController and play video!